# What happens if you define a function in a header file and only use it in a single module?

Tags: c++, linker, header-files

I know defining a header file can cause a linking stage error if the header file is used in multiple modules because you will have multiple definitions of the same function. I know it's bad practice to define a function in a header file but I'm curious as to what happens if the header file has the definition of a function and the header is only used in one module.

Comment: #including a file is the same as copying the file's content at this place. So yes, it will work. But why would you do this?

Comment: There is a simple technique [Include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) which makes all concerns about how often a file is included regardless. Furthermore, a free function defined (aka. implemented) in a header should be marked [inline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) to prevent all potential "duplicate symbol" linker issues. These two things in combination work robust and reliable - much better than the intention to "really include that header once only". ;-)

Comment: I wouldn't do it in practice, I'm just curious as to what would happen. Thanks for the help!